# Embedding content from one to many sites

Tags: wordpress, duplicates, seo, content-management-system, embed

I'm creating a content hub. For example, dental education in my site (let's say chain of clinics) and same content I want to display in my branches websites.

It is possible?
Will it affect SEO?

I want to develop it as a WordPress plugin or embed code as saas.

Answer (score 0):

If the same content is on different domains, then there is a chance that search engines will suspect that the information from one site copied to another, but if the content is on the same domain just as a site for multiple regions, I think it will not be so critical